# Index a list using a nested list

Tags: python, recursion, simulation, genetic-algorithm, nested-lists

I have a list of frequencies (i.e. freq_lst), which need to be retrieved by a nested list in order to do the calculation. The calculation is done using freq_lst and r_freq, illustrated as follows:

```
freq_lst = [0.03571429, 0.03571429, 0.07142857, 0.07142857, 0.10714286, 0.07142857, 0.07142857, 0.03571429, 0.07142857, 0.03571429, 0.03571429, 0.03571429, 0.07142857, 0.03571429, 0.03571429, 0.03571429, 0.03571429, 0.03571429, 0.03571429, 0.03571429]

nested_lst = [['R0','F1','F3','F5','F7','F9','F10'],
['R1','F0','F4','F7','F10','F16'],
['R2','F6','F7','F9','F13','F17','F18'],
['R3','F2','F8','F10','F18','F19'],
['R4','F10','F11','F12','F14','F15','F16']]

r_lst = ['R0','R1','R2','R3','R4']
r_freq = [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3]

def mating_func():
    mating = []
    for k in range(len(r_lst)):
        for k1 in range(len(nested_lst)):
            zgt = 0
            if r_lst[k] == nested_lst[k1][0]:        
                print(freq_lst.index(nested_lst[k1][k2+1] for k2 in range(len(nested_lst[k1]))))
                zgt += r_freq[k] * freq_lst.index(nested_lst[k1][k2+1] for k2 in range(len(nested_lst[k1])))
        mating.append(zgt)
    return mating
```

But instead of getting the frequencies, it only printed the following:

```
<generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>
<generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>
<generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>
<generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>
<generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>
```

I've also tried the following:

```
(nested for-loops shown as before)
for k2 in range(len(nested_lst[k1])):
    if rnase_list[k] == zygotes[k1][0]
        zgt += r_freq[k] * freq_lst.index(nested_lst[k1][k2+1])
```

which rendered the following error:

```
ValueError: 'F1' is not in list
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: <generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>
<generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>
<generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>
<generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>
<generator object mating_func.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x0000020C1D1A8620>

Comment: what do you expect this to do`zgt += r_freq[k] * freq_lst.index(nested_lst[k1][k2+1] for k2 in range(len(nested_lst[k1])))`

Comment: just an FYI `freq_lst.index(<value>)` will return the first index of `<value>` in `freq_list`

Comment: I can't see what the calculation is meant to do, but I think the looping over nested_lst[k1] needs to encompass several lines, and not be put inside the call to 'index'. Did you intend to use a generator that you get now?

Comment: nested_lst[k1][k2+1] returns F1 in first run and clearly it is not in freq_list, that's why it is showing 'F1' is not in list.

Comment: What is the connection between the symbols F1 etc. and the numbers in freq_lst? You look for something in freq_list with 'index', but what you have is a symbol and the list only contains numbers.

Comment: i think in the nested list 'R0' refers to row 0 and F0 refers to the frequency index 0 in freq_list.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson The freq_lst contains all the frequencies of the F#s, i.e. F0, F1, ..., F19, whereas the r_freq contains the frequencies of R0-R4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
mating = []
for k in range(len(r_lst)):
    for k1 in range(len(nested_lst)):
        if r_lst[k] == nested_lst[k1][0]:
            zgt = 0
            zgt+= sum([r_freq[k] * freq_lst[x] for x in [int(i[1:]) for i in nested_lst[k1][1:]]])
    mating.append(zgt)
```

output:

```
[0.028571430000000002,
 0.05000000400000001,
 0.05000000400000001,
 0.050000002,
 0.07500000600000001]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mating = []
for k in range(len(r_lst)):
    for lst in nested_lst:
        if r_lst[k] == lst[0]:
            zgt = 0
            zgt+= sum([r_freq[k] * freq_lst[int(i[1:])] for i in lst[1:]])
    mating.append(zgt)
```

Allow me to simplify a little.